# Difference between Angular interceptors and CORS

Tags: node.js, angular, cors, angular-http-interceptors

I am reading about Angular Interceptors, and I don’t get one thing. Is there a need to use HTTP interceptors in Angular, if let’s say I use CORS in a backend in NodeJS to connect back and front. Do we use interceptors in case where i don’t have custom backend, or is it optional.

I was reading, but as I don’t a single app completely finished, and I am trying to understand the difference between those two. I couldn’t find an adequate answer on this topic.

Comment: There's no requirement to use Angular Interceptors in any situation. They just help with cross-cutting concerns e.g. authentication or logging. when you have something you want to apply to all requests. There's no link either implicit or explicit to CORS.

Comment: You're asking about the difference, about the need when using CORS, about the need when not having a custom backend. Please focus your question, and show your research efforts.

Comment: @trincot I did my research, but after doing it, I couldn't see the exact difference. After I posted the question here, I got my answer. Question was general, not a specific one.

Comment: That's why it has been closed as too broad.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`What is an Angular HTTP Interceptor`

> The angular interceptor is a medium connecting the backend and front-end applications. Whenever a request is made, the interceptors handle it in between. They can also identify the response by performing Rxjs operators.
> The interceptors do not initiate the handle method and handle the requests at their level.

[image]

**Example**
when something you want to apply to all requests like in my case, used Interceptor to add 'Auth Token` to every request.

[More Detail Click Here](https://www.knowledgehut.com/blog/web-development/using-interceptor-in-angular)

`Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)`

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is an HTTP-header based mechanism that allows a server to indicate any origins (domain, scheme, or port) other than its own from which a browser should permit loading resources. CORS also relies on a mechanism by which browsers make a "preflight" request to the server hosting the cross-origin resource, in order to check that the server will permit the actual request. In that preflight, the browser sends headers that indicate the HTTP method and headers that will be used in the actual request.

[image]

**Example** when you access one application from different domain, then you need to allow to access through CORS like in my case, my angular application in on `localhost:4200` and web api on `localhost:4236` so it throws CORS error until I allow my angular domain in my web api by setting CORS configuration in startup of web api.

[More Detail Click Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Don't confused, There is no link between them.

Answer (score -1):

An interceptor in Angular is typically used when you need to do something on every request, like add a header or ensure cookies are sent.

Rather than do this work on potentially lots of individual service methods, the interceptor can do that work from one place.

There is no correlation between CORS requirements and the use of an interceptor.